# About a Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, select-query

I want to get to know the SQL query to find names of a column (egCustomerName) whose names having (anyletter) ‘l’ as the third letter

Comment: I think you are looking for the SQL mid function. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

```
select * from tablename where CustomerName like '__I%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get 3rd letter by using [**SUBSTRING**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

Try something like this:

```
SELECT egCustomerName
FROM Table
WHERE SUBSTRING(egCustomerName, 3, 1) = 'l'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this with both `RIGHT` and `LEFT` functions.

**Query**

```
select name from tblName
where right(left(name,3),1)='l';
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dec942/4)

And can achieve this with `SUBSTRING`,`LIKE`,`MID` also.